# table is breaking when doing item searching using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i've wrote a jquery for searching datas within a table, the code is working but the table is altered. how to keep the entire row where ever the search key is matching

can anyone please tell me some solution for this

this is my jquery code

```
$('#resultSearch').bind('keyup', function() {
            var s = new RegExp(this.value);
            $('#ricGridTable td').each(function() {
                if(s.test(this.innerHTML)) $(this).show();
                else $(this).hide();
            });
        });
```

Comment: You hide/show only td in a row, try hide/show closest tr ( **.closest('tr')** ).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.hide()` is breaking the table because it is setting the `td` to `display:none;`.

Instead use the `visibility:hidden` css attribute, and reveal again with `visibility:visible`.

This is done in jQuery using the `.css()` method `$(this).css('visibility', 'hidden');`

```
$('#resultSearch').bind('keyup', function() {
  var s = new RegExp(this.value);
  $('#ricGridTable td').each(function() {
    if(s.test(this.innerHTML)) $(this).css('visibility', 'visible'); // Show
    else $(this).css('visibility', 'hidden'); // Hide
  });
});
```

However @HB Kautil has pointed out that you should be hiding the row `tr` and not the cell (`td`). In this case `.hide()` will do the job.

```
$(this).parents('tr').hide();
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
$('#resultSearch').bind('keyup', function() {
            var s = new RegExp(this.value);
            $('#ricGridTable td').each(function() {
                if(s.test(this.innerHTML)) $(this).parents('tr').show();
                else $(this).parents('tr').hide();
            });
        });
```